# ESList Not Recognising Indentation In Atom Editor

Tags: javascript, warnings, indentation, atom-editor, eslint

I keep getting this warning in some files in Atom Editor (v1.7.3 latest).

Warning :
`Expected Indentation of 1 tab but found 0`

Image:
[image]

Is there any specific thing I am doing wrong?

EDIT : 
Further to Brett's comment, I started combing through the settings & enabled the 'hard tab' setting. Ive discovered the following:

[image]

On the left side, the editor shows that there are actually spaces there. Even though pressing the tab & when using the arrow keys to move the cursor, it moves a tab's length. Compare that to the right side window, where the indentation is tabs (& no errors reported).

How do I convert the space indentation to tabs?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the lines with warnings have an indentation of 3 spaces instead of a tab.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Ive check and checked again. Its all tabs, not spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I discovered how amazing Atom truly is.

It turns out, its quite easy. Press `ctrl+shift+p` to open the input panel, type in `whitespace : convert spaces to tab` & the editor does the rest.

[image]

A big thank you to @BrettDeWoody for the hint.